# How to create threads from XML file using Java

Tags: java, xml, multithreading

I am new to Java and wanted to know if I have an xml file such as this:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Runners>
<Runner Name="Germany">
<RunnersMoveIncrement>70</RunnersMoveIncrement>
<RestPercentage>10</RestPercentage>
</Runner>
<Runner Name="US">
<RunnersMoveIncrement>10</RunnersMoveIncrement>
<RestPercentage>9</RestPercentage>
</Runner>
<Runner Name="UK">
<RunnersMoveIncrement>20</RunnersMoveIncrement>
    <RestPercentage>7</Restpercentage>
    </Runner>
    <Runner Name="CHINA">

<RunnersMoveIncrement>30</RunnersMoveIncrement>
<RestPercentage>15</RestPercentage>
</Runner>
</Runners>'
```

how do I read this and create threads for this xml file for each of the runner information using the attributes given ? There are so many articles saying so many ways. I am really confused what to do. Can someone give me some idea what to do or a reference as to how to do this?

Comment: read the xml > create the thread bases on what you readed

Comment: Thanks Marco. But how do I do that? I am confused with that part.

Comment: Can someone please guide me with this question? I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several solution to read XML file with Java but I think you have to make the search by yourself. Here comes some trails :

- [Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)
- [DOM Parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)
- [SAX Parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)

According to me, a good programmer is curious ; don't just ask a question and wait for an answer ;)

A simple way to use threads is :

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
       // What you want to do here ...
    }
}
```

or ...

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
       // What you want to do here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fabein I tried reading the XML file but its giving some errors. I am working on resolving them. Thanks for your resources though :) I am still a bit rusty on how do I create threads from what is being read from the XML file

Comment: Thanks a ton @Fabein. I figured out what to do.